How do I keep the literal type information alive?
I have the following code snippet, my question is how do I keep the literal type information of knowLiteral without having to spell out the type like I am doing right now? I want this in JSdoc since that is what I am using. Secondly I want to keep the entire as const type alive.
// @ts-check
/**
 * @typedef {Readonly<Record<string, string>>} ReadonlyStringRecord
 */

/**
 * @template {ReadonlyStringRecord} T
 */
class Main {
    /**
     * @param {T} knowLiteral
     */
    constructor(knowLiteral) {
        /**
         * @readonly
         * @type {T}
         */
        this.knowLiteral = knowLiteral;
    }
}


// how not to have to write this?
/**
 * @extends {Main<{
 *   this_is_know: '42'
 * }>}
 */
class Main2 extends Main {
    constructor() {
        const knowLiteral = /** @type {const} */ ({ 'this_is_know': '42' });
        super(knowLiteral);
    }

    testFunc() {
        //this should (and does) error.
        let x = this.knowLiteral.this_is_not_defined;
    }
}


I suggest you [edit] to write this in TypeScript directly and not JSDoc-annotated JavaScript to get a wider audience. You should also use conventional naming (e.g., thisIs instead of this_is) and grammar (known instead of know).  It looks like this playground link. Could you make that edit or agree for me to do it?

See prev comment. I am going to close this as a duplicate of this question where the answer there would make the example code look like this version.   If you think it's not a duplicate please [edit] to distinguish this question from that one.

@jcalz I don't really understand why you think that that is a duplicate since that question first of all does not use jsdoc which I want to use, I don't what to use  TypeScript directly since my project does not use that. Secondly the answer is 3 years ago and says that it is not possible "The resulting class will no longer be generic" (which is useless for me). Why do I need to modify my question ?

• JSDoc is tangential to the question about keeping type literal information "alive". You can write the same code both with JSDoc and with TS. This is the JSDoc version of my suggestion.  • Nothing significant to the situation here has changed in the last 3 years; type args aren't inferred for super calls. • The resulting class Main2 is not generic in both your example code and in the suggested change. How is it "useless"? • I explained why you should modify the question already; it's fine if you disagree but I don't think reiterating my reasons is helpful to you.

@jcalz I am sorry I reacted a bit hasty, but yeah realizing that it was the super call that was not doing what I wanted was enough I just moved it out of the constructor and now it works thank you, should I close this question?

To keep the literal type information of knowLiteral without manually spelling out the type when extending the Main class, you can utilize TypeScript's ability to infer the type from a constant object. You can do this by defining the literal as a const object and letting TypeScript infer the type automatically.

It already is a const object I don't really understand what you mean? typescript wont infer the generic parameter?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't seem to address the question sufficiently. Could you provide code that demonstrates what you mean (i.e., an answer version of a [mre])? Right now it looks like you're saying that TS can infer the type from the object, which it can, but how does that help having the generic type argument be inferred?
